# FluentNHibernate Automapping not generating mappings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to use Fluent NHibernate auto mappings for the first time.  It appears that the code I'm using isnt generating any mappings.  It has been pretty much copy-pasted from the Auto mapping wiki page.

```
var mappings = AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<MvcBugs.Model.Project>();
mappings.WriteMappingsTo("c:\\temp\\mappings");

var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(mappings))
.Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory())
.ExposeConfiguration(c => { new SchemaExport(c)
    .SetOutputFile("c:\\temp\\schema.sql")
    .Create(false, true); })
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

(also would someone create an auto-mapping tag, I'm too new or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this appears to be a bug.  Removing the line:

```
mappings.WriteMappingsTo("c:\\temp\\mappings");
```

Makes the mappings get set up correctly.